# Multiple Photoswipe galleries Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, photoswipe

I have multiple PhotoSwipe galleries from a list for a portfolio which work perfectly on a Desktop, but only the 1st Gallery shows its images on mobile devices, and the subsequent galleries do not. The PhotoSwipe instance instantiates and I can navigate using the arrows etc, but no images.. any ideas? (I have tried using rel="external" to no avail)

The photoswipe code:

```
function startSwipe(btnId)
{
    var galleryName = btnId;    

(function(window, PhotoSwipe)
{
            var
                options = {
                    preventHide: false,
                    loop: false,
                    captionAndToolbarShowEmptyCaptions: false,
                    getImageSource: function(obj){
                        return obj.url;
                    },
                    getImageCaption: function(obj){
                        return obj.caption;
                    }
                },
                instance = PhotoSwipe.attach( 
                    [
                        { url: 'http://www.example.com/gallery/'+galleryName+'/images/0.jpg'},
                        { url: 'http://www.example.com/gallery/'+galleryName+'/images/1.jpg'},
                        { url: 'http://www.example.com/gallery/'+galleryName+'/images/2.jpg'},

                    ], 
                    options 
                );
                instance.show(0);
    }(window, window.Code.PhotoSwipe));
}
```

and the jqm:

```
<div data-role="content">
<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="a" class="centerLiPort">
    <li id="gal1" onClick="startSwipe(this.id)">
        <div  class="imgDiv"><img src="images/gal1.jpg" ></img></div>
        <a>Gallery 1</a> 
    </li>

    <li id="gal2" onClick="startSwipe(this.id)">
        <div class="imgDiv"><img src="images/gal2.jpg" ></img></div>
        <a>Gallery 2</a>
    </li>

    <li id="gal3" onClick="startSwipe(this.id)">
        <div class="imgDiv" ><img src="images/gal3.jpg" ></img></div>
        <a>Gallery 3</a> 
    </li>
</ul>
</div><!--/content-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I couldn't solve this, the only work around I found was to duplicate the image galleries into the subdomain directories which really stinks, but it works. The error lies somehow in how IOS handles image linking  - as it works perfectly fine on a desktop and other mobile devices.